# Trying to query by date attribute but getting incorrect error

Tags: arcmap, sql

I am using ArcMap 10.8.1 to query features that were edited last Thursday and beyond. Why am I getting this error message about the month not being valid?

> There was an error executing the query.
> Underlying DBMS error [ORA-01843; not a valid month] [FE.TransmissionLine]

[image]

Here is the date format.[image]

Comment: Using ISO 8601 dates is always recommended. Ob. XKCD https://xkcd.com/1179

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I do need to use the 8601 format as recommended above, but also enter the word 'timestamp' in front...

[image]

Without 'timestamp' I get this error:
[image]

Comment: Is this an answer, or just an edit to the original Question?  Oracle has a quirky set of functions for processing dates -- the "timestamp" is a FGDB and SQL Server thing.

Comment: It is an answer. The features are not found without 'timestamp'.

Comment: But you have an error highlighted as part of your solution, which makes it confusing.

Comment: I have now added clarification above the screenshot of the error message to clear up the confusion.